# How do you prevent locked out accounts with JDBC and Java?

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle, jdbc, exception

I currently have a Java application that connects to a SQL Server database and an Oracle database. The issue I'm having is that my code throws the exception for the invalid password too late. A lot of production databases will have a condition that locks out accounts after so many invalid attempts. In my testing, it appears that it keeps trying until it locks itself out, and then it throws the exception with the error message. Any help is appreciated. Code is as follows.

```
 try{
    if (ini.get("Connection", "SQL Server", boolean.class)) {
        dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + ini.get("Connection", "Hostname", String.class) + ":" + ini.get("Connection", "Port", String.class) + ";databaseName=" + ini.get("Connection", "Database", String.class);
        classType = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
        Class.forName(classType);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, userName, password);
    } else if (ini.get("Connection", "Oracle", boolean.class)) {
        classType = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
        dbURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + ini.get("Connection", "Hostname", String.class) + ":" + ini.get("Connection", "Port", String.class) + "/" + ini.get("Connection", "Instance", String.class);
        Class.forName(classType);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, userName, password);
    } else if (ini.get("Connection", "ODBC", boolean.class)){
        classType = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
        dbURL = "jdbc:odbc:scoreboard";
        Class.forName(classType);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, "", "");
    } else {
        classType = "net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver";
        Class.forName(classType);
        String Path = ini.get("Connection", "Access Path", String.class);;
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://" + Path);
    }
}
catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
    "<html><body><p style='width: 200px;'> "+"Error Defining Database Connection Method: " + e.getMessage()+"</p></body></html>", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    ini.put("Connection", "Success", false);
}
finally{
    try { if(con!=null){
            con.close();
        } 
    } catch (Exception e) { /* ignored*/ }
}
```

Comment: The code you've displayed is only doing a `getConnection` once.

Comment: Should there be another getConnection?

Comment: The code you posted should only cause a single invalid login attempt.  Of course, my guess is that you really have an application that many different people are hitting (or that one person retries when an error occurs) and that each of those individual errors accumulate until the database account is locked.  If you're using a fixed username & password to connect to the database, most organizations prevent those accounts from being locked and coordinate with the application server admins when the password does change.

Comment: Initially, I thought the same. But in my testing environment, with only me using the application, the application just keeps attempting until the lock out. Unfortunately, the DBAs for the organization this is for will not remove the security lockout for the account used with this.

Comment: My point is the same as Justin's. The code shown wouldn't cause a lockout since it only tries to connect once. We don't have the full code, so it's not easy to say what is actually going on. Using a debugger would probably be very helpful for you here.

Comment: Then something outside this code is initiating the retry.  Or this code is being executed multiple times to do something like establishing a connection pool.

Comment: I'll look into the rest of the code in depth. Thanks for the help guys and I'll post if I find a resolution in case it's something funky.